# Mirroring C struct in Python using ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I tried to mirror a C struct in Python using ctypes.

**c_file.c**:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct SomeStructure{
    int age;
    char c;
    char* name;
};

double someFunction(struct SomeStructure *s){
    printf("My age is %d and my c is %s and finally name is %s", s->age, s->c, s->name);
    return 42;
}
```

I compile the C file using:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o clibrary.so c_file.c
```

The python code.

**py_file.py**

```
import ctypes

clibrary = ctypes.CDLL(".\clibrary.so")

class SomeStructure(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('age', ctypes.c_int),
        ('c', ctypes.c_char),
        ('name', ctypes.c_char_p)
    ]

clibrary.someFunction.restype = ctypes.c_double
clibrary.someFunction.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(SomeStructure)]

obj = SomeStructure(13, 'm', b"Jo")
clibrary.someFunction(ctypes.byref(obj))
```

I got error:

```
    obj = SomeStructure(13, 'm', b"Jo")
TypeError: one character bytes, bytearray or integer expected
```

Comment: `'m'` is a Unicode character, which is bigger than the `char` type you're trying to store it in.  Write that as `b'm'` to make it a `bytes` object, just like you did with the anemia.

Comment: @jasonharper. Thank you. I got the error, `    clibrary.someFunction(ctypes.byref(obj))
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x000000000000006D` after passing `b'm'`

Comment: Your C `printf` should be `c is %c` for the `char`-type variable as well and is the cause of the crash.